# Rails server side job to create vendors in QuickBooks Online

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, quickbooks-online

I have a rails web based app which has users which will be vendors in QuickBooks Online. Users will signup in my rails application with email address and these users will be verified by Admin at EOD manually. I want to write a service/job in rails which will connect to QuickBooks online and create the verified users as vendors in QuickBooks.

My problem is QuickBooks rest API uses OAuth which requires user to enter quickbooks user and password on UI to get the token but my service will be offline, so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is QuickBooks rest API uses OAuth which requires user to enter quickbooks user and password on UI

... exactly ONCE, and then NEVER AGAIN.

Repeat - You only have to log in ONCE, and ONLY ONCE, and then NEVER AGAIN.

Log in once, the very first time you deploy your Rails app, and then never log in again.

There should be no issue here. The docs cover this as well:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/000500_authentication_and_authorization/0005_your_app_user_experience
- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/000500_authentication_and_authorization/connect_from_within_your_app
- https://oauth.net/core/1.0/#auth_step3

Comment: +100 I'll just add that the quickbooks-ruby gem is great and its readme explains how to setup OAuth and best practices for persisting the credentials https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby#persisting-the-credentials